# Magento config.xml system.xml adminhtml.xml

Tags: magento

Can anyone pls shed some light on below topic ?

What is a clear difference between Magento's etc/ config.xml, system.xml and adminhtml.xml ?

What code differentiate three of the above XML files ?

It is just for the core magento knowledge.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `config.xml` files contain global configuration information for Magento, available to all Magento "areas".  In the beginning, there were no `adminhtml.xml` configuration files.  This information was located in `config.xml`.  Later versions of Magento broke this information out into `adminhtml.xml` files, and only merged these files with the other `config.xml` files when the system was serving backend admin pages.

The `system.xml` files are **not** a part of the global configuration.  They're a separate system for automatically building UI in the backend application for setting system configuration values.

**How** Magento loads these files is a long involved tale that's not appropriate for a Stack Overflow answer.  I have a [four article series that covers this in detail](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config) if you're interested in that sort of thing.

The short version is `config.xml` files are loaded here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
$this->loadModulesConfiguration(array('config.xml',$resourceConfig), $this);
```

The `adminhtml.xml` files are loaded here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Config.php
Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('adminhtml.xml', $adminhtmlConfig);
```

and `system.xml` files are loaded here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config.php
$config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')
->applyExtends();
```